CMake target_link_libraries for boost-python is the variable ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} needed?
I am following Advanced C++ / Python integration with Boost.Python tutorial to get a get a grasp on Boost-Python lib.
In the example above I have:
hello.cpp :
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

std::string multi_bob(int n)
{
   std::string name = "Bob";
   std::string r = "";
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
      r += name;
   return r;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
    def("multibob", multi_bob);
    
}


CMakeFileLists.txt :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
 
project(greeter)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_VERSION -----> ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES ---> ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")

# Find necessary packages
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES ---> ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES ---> ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")


find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
 
# Build & Link our library
add_library(hello MODULE hello.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})


target_link_libraries(hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

# don't prepend wrapper library name with lib
set_target_properties(hello PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

and the Python script to use the compiled module; main.py:
# demo.py

import hello

print(hello.greet())
print(hello.multibob(17))

The original example has in CMakeFileLists.txt a line that reads:
target_link_libraries(hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
but I am able to compile and run the code with this line too:
target_link_libraries(hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) .
${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} is found by find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
but is not used, or is it?
target_link_libraries from CMake Docs  says :

Specify libraries or flags to use when linking a given target and/or its dependents. Usage requirements from linked library targets will be propagated. Usage requirements of a target's dependencies affect compilation of its own sources.

So my question is, why all the examples found online use target_link_libraries(hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}) ? What am I missing ?

you can probably just link to boost::python and remove everything else in target_link_libraries, linking using variables is error prone as typos silently resolve to an empty string, you wouldn't need include_directories then either as the target sets that for you too

thanks, is it something that has to do with CMake version upgrades ? Is there any specific link in docs. Tried to read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html but too difficult to understand for a newbie like me Thank you indeed for your prompt reply though

The names of the modern targets are documented in the FindXXX documentation. In this case: FindBoost

There is a python example in the exanples section of that FindBoost link: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html#examples
